# python - Precise control of matplotlib plot labels' position

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I want to plot a 2D graph using matplotlib and I want my plot labels to be offset not only in one axis but both. For example I want my horizontal (x) labels to be offset on the vertical axis by a certain amount but also on the horizontal axis a different amount.

So far I have only found this:

`axes.tick_params(axis="x", direction="in", pad=-10)`

Which only manipulates the label position on one axis.

Is there a way/hack to get more precise control of my labels?

Comment: Isn't the default option for `tick_params` is `axis='both'`?

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'm not trying to pad the labels of both axes. I'm trying to move the (let's say) horizontal labels both vertically and horizontally.